# Umbraco - Crete a list of items

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

Helo ,

I am quiet new to umbraco. I want to reate a page which will show a list of items which should be added in administration section. Any tutorials on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to manage the list as an admin (ie you as the dev) or as an editor (ie whoever manages the content).

If it's you managing the list then you could use one of the custom data types that come with uComponents to manage a list - eitehr as an Enum, or as a list of content or as an SQL table

If you want an editor to manage it - and this is usually my preferred route, You could create a content data type purely for managing lists and create your items as a child data type below that. You can then use either the API to get what you want out of the list, or again one of the controls that comes with uComponents.

If you give some more details I can help you with it perhaps

thanks,
Carl

Comment: Not really - but basically I would create a document type that wasn't part of the main site content (perhaps at the same level) and then add all your content under that.

Comment: If you only want to show the list in the front end of the website, you could add a macro (either a razor macro or xslt depending on your preference) that calls the API to list the items

Comment: You could use the example macro "list children from a changeable source" and set it up

Comment: Or if you trusted me, give me the credentials for a demo site that you host somewhere and I can set it up for you - will take about 2 mins approximately :)